# JSONDecoderError: Expected value line 1 column 1 error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, json

I'm putting a predictive model into production. When I run requests.post in the code below, I get an error: JSONDecoderError: Expected value line 1 column 1 error

If I remove .json() from the end, it runs fine, so I'm thinking it's saying the customer is not json. But I've looked over customer and it appears to be correct.  Would anything else cause this error?

```
import requests

url='http://localhost:9696/predict'

customer = {
    "gender": "female",
    "seniorcitizen": 0,
    "partner": "yes",
    "dependents": "no",
    "phoneservice": "no",
    "multiplelines": "no_phone_service",
    "internetservice": "dsl",
    "onlinesecurity": "no",
    "onlinebackup": "yes",
    "deviceprotection": "no",
    "techsupport": "no",
    "streamingtv": "no",
    "streamingmovies": "no",
    "contract": "month-to-month",
    "paperlessbilling": "yes",
    "paymentmethod": "electronic_check",
    "tenure": 24,
    "monthlycharges": 29.85,
    "totalcharges": (24 * 29.85)
}

requests.post(url,json=customer).json()
```

Comment: Check the return status code of your post!

Comment: It finds the predict.py file and prints the HTML source code when I ask it to print the first 400 characters.

Answer (score 0):

`.json()` actually tries to convert the response retrieved from `http://localhost:9696/predict` into a dictionary.

The error is happening due to the fact that your endpoint is not returning a JSON object. Perhaps you can try and check if:

1. Your endpoint is actually returning a valid JSON?
2. Check the output with `print(requests.post(url,json=customer).text)`